# How can I make my nav bar not overlap on mobile

Tags: html, css

The navbar I created overlaps when I switch my site to a mobile view.

I tried making it fit-content, but it still overlaps. The part that overlaps is the listed items

```css
#navBar {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: double black 2px;
}

#navBar ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: fit-content;
}

#navBar li {
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
}

#navBar a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid lime;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: American Typewriter, serif;
  color: #262626;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
}

#navBar a:hover {
  color: lime;
}

#navBar a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

#navBar::hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navBar">
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="test1.php">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="test2.php">Tab2</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="test3.php">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I expect the navbar items to be side by side but the actual result in them overlapping.

Comment: You can simply use media query to change view on mobile pixels that they should align in column view

Comment: This link will help you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inline-flex` for that

change

```
#navBar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; /* reset margin */
  list-style: none;
  width: fit-content;
}

#navBar li {
  display: inline-flex; /* change to inline-flex and remove the padding */
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
#navBar {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: double black 2px;
}

#navBar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: fit-content;
}

#navBar li {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

#navBar a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid lime;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: American Typewriter, serif;
  color: #262626;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
}

#navBar a:hover {
  color: lime;
}

#navBar a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

#navBar::hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navBar">
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="test1.php">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="test2.php">Tab2</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="test3.php">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```